# How to call parent module method from child module in requirejs?

Tags: requirejs

I have a module that has 2 sub module dependencies. In the parent module there is a method that I would like to call from both child modules. How could I do that?

Is there another way then passing the parent module object to the child module constructor?

```
define(['child1', 'child2'], function (child1, child2) {
  return {
    init: function () {
      child1.init();
      child2.init();
    },
    parentMethod: function() {
      console.log('called');
    }
  }
});

/*child1*/
define(function() {
  return {
    init: function() {
      //call parentMethod()
    }
  }
});

/*child2*/
define(function() {
  return {
    init: function() {
      //call parentMethod()
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

RequireJS has no notion of parent-child relationship between modules. Given that modules are singletons, and that a module like `child1` could be loaded by multiple modules (for instance, loaded by `parent1` and `parent2`), then which module should RequireJS consider to be the *real* parent of `child1`?

Passing a reference to the parent to your children's `init()` function is really the way to go.

Comment: I did that (pass the object to the children's init), but I was looking for another way to do it. Maybe another architecture? A better practice?

Comment: A better practice might be to have the children emit an event (using jQuery or an event library), and have the parent handle the event.  Ideally, the children should have no knowledge of the parent, so it should be the parent's job to know how to handle the event(s) being emitted.

Comment: @kevin.groat I use event in some cases and references to other modules/classes/instances in other cases. It really depends on the details of the problem to be solved. I've got libraries where using event emitters would amount to over-engineering. I've got libraries where *not* using event emitters would result in too-tight coupling.